# Creating css transitions without using position:absolute

Tags: css, css-transitions

I realize that css animations are a well covered topic, but I'm just wondering about the best way to create simple slide like transitions? Mostly, when you read about slide transitions like that, some kind of position:absolute is assumed. That is not the way content is usually organized in HTML and it shouldn't be.

So, if I want to create a transition of one div sliding to the left and one div sliding from the right, what would be a good strategy without assuming that any of those divs has absolute positioning or any other specific transition specific stuff going on to start with?

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="this-should-slide-left">
         <div>Some content</div>
         <div>Some more</div>
     </div>
     <div class="this-should-from-left"><!--not visible initially-->
         <div>Some more content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I came up with this solution which seems to work, even though I'm not sure if it's elegant:

http://jsfiddle.net/CAg4f/4/

Answer (score 7):

The best way to move elements around when animating is translating using css transforms.
For example, to transition when hovering over the container:

```
.this-should-slide-left,
.this-should-from-left {
    transition: transform .25s
}

.container .this-should-from-left {
    transform: translateX(100px);
}

.container:hover  .this-should-from-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container:hover .this-should-slide-left {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

Translating makes the transition much smoother as it takes advantage of hardware acceleration plus there is no positioning involved, so you have complete separation between the design of the layout and the design of the animation itself.

[Read more here](http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/)

Comment: I had a go at that. The problems I'm running into are to get the from left element appear as arriving from the right. In stead of appearing below the to-left item and then being animated from the right.

Also, I used animation for the from-right item to allow me to set the starting position outside of the container.

    .this-should-from-left{
 -webkit-animation: from-right 1s ease-in; 
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes from-right {
 from{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
 }
 to{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 }
}

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer OP's question!?!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `absolute` positioning, there is `relative` positioning and `margins`.

While I would usually go with `margins` to manipulate a transition, `relative` positioning is probably the safest, as it will work for `inline` elements which can't necessarily be manipulated by margins.

Comment: The problem with margins is that if you transition to marginLeft:-10000px; on a div with a background-color, you basically get a big stretch effect because the "this-should-slide-left" div will  take up the full width of the containing div

Comment: @Marc Yea, that's true. It all depends on the situation, really. `relative` positioning would be your best option.